# ​ Collection helpers meteor-dburles-collection-helpers with typescript

Tags: typescript, meteor

I am using `dburles:collection-helpers` in my meteor 2.12 project with typescript. I added this package with `meteor add dburles:collection-helpers` and the types with `meteor yarn add @types/meteor-dburles-collection-helpers`.

In my TS file:

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
...
interface IBackupJobs {
  status: "queued" |
      "in_progress" |
      "restarting" |
      "finished_ok" |
      "finished_error"
...
}

const BackupJobsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  status: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: [
      "queued",
      "in_progress",
      "restarting",
      "finished_ok",
      "finished_error"
    ]
  },
...
});
const BackupJobs = new Mongo.Collection<IBackupJobs>("backup_jobs");
BackupJobs.attachSchema(BackupJobsSchema);
BackupJobs.helpers({
  isRunning() {
    return (
      this.status === "queued" ||
      this.status === "in_progress" ||
      this.status === "restarting"
    );
  }
});
```

But muy IDE gives me an error in `BackupJobs.helpers`: Property 'helpers' does not exist on type Collection<Document, Document>

I tried to put the types files from `meteor-dburles-collection-helpers` in my own `typings-custom` project folder but I got the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I find that adding a `import 'meteor-dburles-collection-helpers'` fixes this, but I must to add a `isRunning` property to `IBackupJobs`. So the interface is:

```
interface IBackupJobs {
  status: "queued" |
      "in_progress" |
      "restarting" |
      "finished_ok" |
      "finished_error"
...
  isRunning: () => boolean
}
```